# Filtering CSV file

Tags: csvsimple

I managed to confuse myself with filtering data from a CSV file. For example, in the below example, how do I insert the relevant text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents}{bible.csv}
chapter,verse,text
1,1,{test chapter 1, verse 1}
2,1,{test chapter 2, verse 1}
2,2,{test chapter 2, verse 2}
2,3,{test chapter 2, verse 3}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
    <the text of chapter 2 verse 3 to be inserted here>
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
    <the text of chapter 2 verse 1 to 3 to be inserted here>
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

by checking the manual of [`csvsimple13`](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple-l3.pdf), sec. 4.5 **Line range** p27, we can specify the rows to be displayed. In your case, you want a single row and column named "text". So:

```latex
\csvreader[
head to column names,
range = 2
]{bible.csv}{}{%
    \text
}
```

The command `\text` allows selecting the column, `range = 2` allows specifying the row.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents}{bible.csv}
chapter,verse,text
1,1,{test chapter 1, verse 1}
2,1,{test chapter 2, verse 1}
2,2,{test chapter 2, verse 2}
2,3,{test chapter 2, verse 3}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\csvreader[
head to column names,
range = 2
]{bible.csv}{}{%
    \text
}
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
\csvreader[
head to column names,
range = 1-3
]{bible.csv}{}{%
    \text
}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using the `readarray` and `listofitems` packages.  I'm not sure if the format of your input file is rigid or not.  The code could be streamlined significantly if the input file were in a simpler format. Nonetheless, using the OP's specified format, the result can be achieved.  **Note that this approach allows verse ranges to be specified across chapter boundaries.**

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems}
\ignoreemptyitems
\begin{filecontents}{bible.csv}
chapter,verse,text
1,1,{test chapter 1, verse 1}
2,1,{test chapter 2, verse 1}
2,2,{test chapter 2, verse 2}
2,3,{test chapter 2, verse 3}
3,1,{test chapter 3, verse 1}
3,2,{test chapter 3, verse 2}
\end{filecontents}

\def\chapvrses[#1,#2]-[#3,#4]{%
  \ifnum#1=#3
    \inchapvrses{#1}{#2}{#4}%
  \else
    \foreachitem\zz\in\chapvrs[]{%
      \ifnum\zzcnt<#1\else
        \ifnum\zzcnt>#3\else
          \ifnum\zzcnt=#1
            \inchapvrses{#1}{#2}{\listlen\chapvrs[#1]}\
          \else
            \ifnum\zzcnt=#3
              \inchapvrses{#3}{1}{#4}%
            \else
              \inchapvrses{\zzcnt}{1}{\listlen\chapvrs[\zzcnt]}\
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  \fi 
}
\newcommand\inchapvrses[3]{%
  \foreachitem\z\in\chapvrs[#1]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt<#2\else
      \ifnum\zcnt>#3\else
        \ifnum\zcnt=#2\else\ \fi
        \z
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\begin{document}
% Read file into macro
\readarraysepchar{;}
\readdef{bible.csv}\Bible

% Convert format into something easier: verse, verse; new-chapter-verse, verse, etc.
\newtoks\zzz
\newcommand\addtozzz[1]{\global\zzz\expandafter{\the\zzz#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtozzz[1]{\expandafter\addtozzz\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\xxaddtozzz[1]{\expandafter\xaddtozzz\expandafter{#1}}
\newcounter{Bibchap}
\setsepchar{;/,}
\readlist\chapvrs{\Bible}
\foreachitem\z\in\chapvrs[]{%
  \ifnum\zcnt=1\else
    \ifnum\theBibchap=0 \stepcounter{Bibchap}\else
      \ifnum\chapvrs[\zcnt,1]=\theBibchap\relax
        \addtozzz{,}%
      \else
        \stepcounter{Bibchap}%
        \addtozzz{;}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \xxaddtozzz{\chapvrs[\zcnt,3]}%
  \fi
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\Bible\expandafter{\the\zzz}

% Read \Bible (in preferred format) as a list
\readlist\chapvrs{\Bible}
\begin{quote}
    \chapvrs[2,3]
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
    \chapvrses[2,2]-[3,1]
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one instead chose a simpler file format, with no indexing numbers in the file, just comma verse separators and semicolon chapter separators:

```
{verse}, 
{verse}; 
{new-chapter-verse}, 
{verse}, 
etc.
```

the code would simplify as

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems}
\ignoreemptyitems
\begin{filecontents}{bible.csv}
{test chapter 1, verse 1};
{test chapter 2, verse 1},
{test chapter 2, verse 2},
{test chapter 2, verse 3};
{test chapter 3, verse 1},
{test chapter 3, verse 2};
\end{filecontents}

\def\chapvrses[#1,#2]-[#3,#4]{%
  \ifnum#1=#3
    \inchapvrses{#1}{#2}{#4}%
  \else
    \foreachitem\zz\in\chapvrs[]{%
      \ifnum\zzcnt<#1\else
        \ifnum\zzcnt>#3\else
          \ifnum\zzcnt=#1
            \inchapvrses{#1}{#2}{\listlen\chapvrs[#1]}\
          \else
            \ifnum\zzcnt=#3
              \inchapvrses{#3}{1}{#4}%
            \else
              \inchapvrses{\zzcnt}{1}{\listlen\chapvrs[\zzcnt]}\
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  \fi 
}
\newcommand\inchapvrses[3]{%
  \foreachitem\z\in\chapvrs[#1]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt<#2\else
      \ifnum\zcnt>#3\else
        \ifnum\zcnt=#2\else\ \fi
        \z
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{}
\readdef{bible.csv}\Bible
\setsepchar{;/,}
\readlist\chapvrs{\Bible}
\begin{quote}
    \chapvrs[2,3]
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
    \chapvrses[2,2]-[3,1]
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```